# How can I collapse 2 seperate twitter bootstrap navbars into 1 menu?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to have 2 bootstrap navbars. 1 below the other. However, when I view this on a mobile phone it shows 2 [=] buttons, 1 for each navbar. Is there a way to have 2 separate navbars and when they collapse to join into 1 menu that is all under the same expand button [=]?

I know I can hack this together with duplicate links and hidden-xs classes, but I am wondering if there is a better option.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the discussion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810982/two-navbars-collapsed-into-1-for-mobile?newreg=19d34c73fd4c47c2ada61b6785b62754. It worked for me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's not possible to use single toggle button for two navbars. If you look this question [Two Responsive Nav bar in Bootsrap Page Conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158664/two-responsive-nav-bar-in-bootsrap-page-conflicts) you can see that if the menus have same data-target then you can use either button. And your can hide one button through css.